# com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: (Internal)

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a game using libgdx, when I run the game from my PC using the desktop launcher I have no errors and it works perfectly. When I connect my phone and I try to execute directly on it, I get this error

[errorlibgdx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YneVL.jpg)

It's like the device couldn't find the files inside the assets folder. Did I have to change some directory paths? 
This is where "hero.pack" is loaded by libgdx

public class PlayScreen extends FatherScreen {

```
    private Hero player;
    private TextureAtlas heroatlas;


public PlayScreen (MyGdxGame game, String levelname, Music music){
    super(game, levelname, music);

    heroatlas = new TextureAtlas("hero.pack"); 


...
```

}

accept

@m.antkowicz this is the hero.pack code:

`hero.png
  format: RGBA8888
  filter: Nearest,Nearest
  repeat: none
  hero
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 705, 49
  orig: 705, 49
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1`

It's a simple code of an animation of the hero character. @manabreak the hero.pack file is in the android/assets folder on my PC. As I said before I have no problem running the game directly on my PC! Maybe I have to copy the assets folder on the phone directly?

Comment: It found file actually - the problem is that TextureAtlas class cannot proceed this. Could you please attach your .pack file as an edit of a question?

Comment: @m.antkowicz The exception specifically says "FileNotFoundException" - that means the file was not found.

Comment: @Morpheus2490 Where did you place the "hero.pack" file? It should go into "android/assets" folder (or any subfolder).

Comment: I added the code of "hero.pack" file!